# Parse an OCL Expression into an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, ocl

**for context** - the OCL Expressions will be given alongside an "Ecore" file that holds information regarding the UML that the expression is associated with.

As a part of a research I'm conducting I'm trying to parse an OCL Expression into an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) which I want to be able to iterate through, see information for each node, and make changes. The problem is that all the software I found that have anything to do with OCL either -
aren't supported by modern applications because they are just too out of date or are meant to validate an expression or return a boolean value for the expression given an instance of a certain model.

I did manage to view an AST for a given Expression using Eclipse MDE but that was only through the UI with no option to export it (as far as I noticed).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zu2b.jpg)

The closest solution I found was DresdenOCL (https://github.com/dresden-ocl/standalone) which after scouting the code for a long while I found a function that returns a "TreeIterator" Object for a certain "OCLResource" object. The problem is the nodes on the tree are made up of classes that were meant for backend use only - meaning I can't get any real information out of them except for the class name, memory location and sometimes a string value that represents a part of the Expression. The fact that there is no indication of hierarchy except for the order in which it was printed in is also a big issue. I also tried using Reflection on these nodes but from what I saw those classes don't have any useful functions or fields that might help.

I've also provided some photos as an example including input and output.
Photos:

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9v5O.jpg)

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPFTH.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6azFP.jpg)

My best option at the moment is to painstakingly study these DresdenOCL outputs until I have a good understanding of how they are built and then write a code myself that takes these outputs and builds an AST that I can work with properly, but that might take a long time, which is why I'm bringing the issue here hoping that some beautiful stranger might show up with a better solution.

any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have more luck with USE-OCL (by Uni Bremen, available at [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/useocl/)). It is open-source, and in the package src/main/org/tzi/parser you find an AST representation with its node elements, along with parser/compiler classes to create the AST from a String input. It seems pretty comprehensive and might be suitable for an integration into another tool.

I have not worked with USE's code myself yet, but I use the tool in lectures. It is reliable, stable and actively maintained.

Edit: The following snippet transforms an OCL Expression into the compiled internal representation you can find in package `org.tzi.use.uml.ocl.expr`. Looking at the function `compileExpression` you can find how to transform into the AST representation of package `org.tzi.use.parser.ocl`. Whatever suits you better. The used UML model is empty, therefore there is not context to be used in the expression. However, transforming a model into the USE model format might not be too much effort.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        ModelFactory mFactory = new ModelFactory();
        MModel mModel = mFactory.createModel("unnamed");
        MSystem system = new MSystem(mModel);
        
        String input = "Set{1,2,3} ->collect(i|i*2)";
        
        PrintWriter errorPrinter = new PrintWriter(new StringWriter(), true);
        
        Expression expr = OCLCompiler.compileExpression(mModel, input,
                "USE Api", errorPrinter, system.varBindings());
        
        System.out.println(expr.toString());
    }
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the quick answer, I did try USE-OCL but emberassingly i didnt really know where to start, the program seems huge and every class is dependant on so many others, can you direct me to which file in src/main/org/tzi/parser i should start looking?

Comment: src/main/org/tzi/use/parser/use/USECompiler.java::compilesSpecification(...) compiles an entire model (including the non-OCL parts). src/main/org/tzi/use/parser/AST is the top-level AST structure. And in the sub-package ocl you find the OCL-related syntax nodes.

Comment: thanks again for your help, I opened up the entire Use project in Intellij and im looking through it but at the moment I cant find a java class that gets a string input and starts parsing it, its all very convoluted. in addition to that, is it possible to parse a OCL expression with USE outside the context of a model? because it seems the program has its own format when it comes to models, and unless i can easily generate it from an Ecore file, that would also be a problem.

Comment: The edit in the post above shows how to parse/compile an OCL expression to two different representations with an empty model.

Comment: Thanks alot! From your code i managed to piece together the process which was unknown to me beforehand. because i have an entire dataset of models with expressions i need to find a way to automate the entire process and build models dynamically. 

i did manage to change the code so that the CompileExpression function returns an ASTexpression Type. I'm still trying to understand the best way to iterate through the object but you really helped me with getting started the right way.

An additional request If I may, do you know of any documentation regarding using USE outside of the UI?

TY!

Comment: I know of nothing other than the documents you find under documentation in the wiki http://useocl.sourceforge.net/w/index.php/Main_Page#Documentation

Answer (score 1):

Using the Complete OCL editor from Eclipse OCL you can use the OCL -> Save Abstract Syntax context menu action, or indeed Save Concrete (Xtext) Syntax. The underlying functionality is Java callable if you need programmatic saving.

You should be aware that the AST defined by the OMG OCL specification has many inadequacies for which the Pivot-based Eclipse OCL prototypes solutions.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i did try out Eclipse OCL but i did not manage to get to the point where I can save an AST, the menu appearing after clicking on OCL only allows to validate expression, export document (which saves it as .ocl format) or show Xtext console which opens up a blank console.

Comment: Seems like you are using the Ecore / OCLinEcore editor for which the AST is Ecore with the OCL embedded as EAnnotation textual bodies. Only Complete OCL has a comprehensive AST. You can Export Document from Ecore /OCLinEcore to give you a Complete OCL document that can then be edited and saved as a full AST. You can see some examples of a full AST in https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/ocl/org.eclipse.ocl/+/refs/heads/master/plugins/org.eclipse.ocl.pivot/model-gen/OCL-2.5.oclas